# PHPのシングルクォート記述でシンタックスエラーが発生する

Tags: php

PHPの開発に挑戦しだしてまもないものです。
今までterapadのエディタでコーディングを進めてきたのですが、Eclipseでの作業に切替えたいと考え、https://techacademy.jp/magazine/1620　を参考に環境構築に挑戦しだしています。
記事がちょっと古かったので、記事とは異なるEclipse　4.7 oxygenなる最新版をダウンロードしました。XAMPPのセットアップも終え、一応にPHPとApacheもそれなりに入ったのかな？という認識から、早速記事にあるphpのコーディングをコピペしてtest.phpを作成してみました。

### 質問

下記画像にあるとおりtest.phpはSyntaxエラーと思しき事象が発生しています。シングルクォート内の文字列に対した指摘のようでちょっと困惑しております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①これは一体何の原因でしょうか？以下が実際のコーディングです。

```
<?php
 $a = ‘Hello eclise<br>’;
echo $a;
 $b = ‘Hello Pleiades All in One 日本語ディストリビューション<br>’;
echo $b;
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```

②xamppまかせでインストールしたのですが、phpのVerが気になって、php.infoのありかを探して
http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php
にアクセスしてみました。
残念ながら期待（7.0）のVERではなかったのですが（5.6）、phpのみをVerUpすることはできるのでしょうか

### 追記

@OOPer @RNeJRHXaFXmjY ご見解をありがとうございます。

①について仰られるとおりでした、単純なことでお手間をとらせて申し訳ございませんでした。
②について、[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42628/19110)として投稿したのでご確認下さい。

Comment: 1つ目は「PHPの文法に関する」質問で、正直Eclipseの話はあまり関連が無いかと。2つ目は「PHP（XAMPP）のインストールに関する」質問なので、既に指摘されていますが質問を分けた方がよいと思います。

Comment: @cubick 了解です、少々お待ち下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

①該当の記事ですが、ニュートラルのシングルクオート(`'` U+0027 APOSTROPHE)になるべきところが、左シングルクオート(`‘` U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)と右シングルクオート(`’` U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)に化けてしまっているようで、コード全体をそのままコピペしても使えないようになっています。

シングルクオートに見える`‘`や`’`の部分をキーボードを英数入力状態にして入力しなおしてみると良いでしょう。

```
<?php
 $a = 'Hello eclise<br>';
echo $a;
 $b = 'Hello Pleiades All in One 日本語ディストリビューション<br>';
echo $b;
 phpinfo();
```

②については、最近XAMPPを使っていないので、よくわからないというのが正直なところですが。オールインワンになっているのがXAMPPの最大の利点なので、アンインストールしてご所望のPHPバージョンのXAMPPを入れ直した方がいいのではないかと思います。

Comment: ご支援をありがとうございます、助かります。
本文へ追記を図りました。ご確認を頂けますと幸いです、
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: @saya24 , エラーメッセージの中に _missing　dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method_ とあり、ポートの問題以外に「依存性の欠如、不適切な権限設定、クラッシュ、他のメソッドによるシャットダウン」なども挙げられており、しかもその内のどれかが本当に原因なのかどうかもわかりません。私の知っている限りだとXAMPPのPHPはApacheの拡張モジュールとなっており、PHPモジュールの読み込みがエラーになればこのようなメッセージが出るはずです。どのバージョンのコンパイラでコンパイルしたか、関係するファイルをどのパスに配置する設定になっているかなどが違えばうまく読み込めなかったりします。他のコメントありますように質問を新たに書き直されるのであれば(そうすべきだと思いますが)、・プラットフォームのOS名(Windowsだと思いますが)とバージョン、元のXAMPPの正確なバージョンなどを示された方がより適切な回答を得られる可能性が高まるかと思います。本文中に書いたように私がお手伝いできる可能性は低そうですが、インストールされたフォルダ構成の一部を書き換えるなんてことをするとアンインストーラがうまく動かなくなることもあるので、お気をつけください。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

【1】
ご提示のソースはシングルクォート（'）ではなく
バッククォート（`）で囲まれているのでエラーが出ているのではないでしょうか。
（ご提示のソースを当方のIDEにコピペしたらそうなりました）

ソースを以下のようにしてみて下さい。

```
    <?php
    $a = "Hello eclise<br>";
    echo $a;
     $b = "Hello Pleiades All in One 日本語ディストリビューション<br>";
    echo $b;
     phpinfo();
     ?>
```

上記はわかりやすいようダブルクォートというもので囲っています。

phpにおけるシングルクォートとダブルクォートは少し動きが違うので
合わせてご確認することをお勧めいたします。

http://php-beginner.com/reference/basic/escape.html

【2】
xampp未経験ですが、再インストールしたほうが
後々のバグが少なく作業量的にも少ない気がします。
https://nendeb.com/330

Comment: ご支援をありがとうございます、助かります。
本文へ追記を図りました。ご確認を頂けますと幸いです、
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: いただいたコンソールメッセージに
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
とありますがこのlogボタンを押した後
詳細のログが出ると思います。

そちらをご提示いただいてわかるようでしたら
またコメントさせていただきます。
apacheもあまり詳しくないものですみません^^；

しかし、そちらを新しい質問として立てたほうが
解決が早くなるかもしれません。
（apacheのエラーになると思うので少しインフラよりの質問となりますので）

Comment: ご支援をありがとうございます、大事なことを伝え忘れていました。
Apacheのerrorログに、Apache起動時間帯のログが一切記述されていないのです。一応accessログも確認しましたが
Apacheの開始時時間帯の記述が一切ありません。

別スレッドを立てるべきかな

Comment: ログのご確認ありがとうございます。ログもないとなると厳しいですね。xamppのエラーメッセージで検索して予想を立てるしかありません。OOPerさんが詳しい解説を書いてくださっていますのでやはりxamppの心得がある方に聞くほうが得策かと思います。力及ばずですみません。