# XAMPP同梱のPHPを個別にバージョンアップしたらApacheが起動しなくなった

Tags: php, apache

本件は[前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42623/19110)の中で、二つ目にお問い合わせしていた内容です。
タイトルと二つ目の問い合わせ内容に、だいぶ乖離があるので、別の案件として再掲載させて頂きました。

#### 背景

PHPの開発をEclipseへ切り替えるべく、日本語化プラグイン・Xamppも同梱のEclipse 4.7 oxygenをWindows7 x86端末へセットアップしました。
PHP・Apache2.4の動作を一応確認致しましたがPHPのVerが期待外であったため、PHPのみを5.6から7.0へのVerUpを図ろうとしました。

#### 現在の問題点

この作業を行う上で、 https://thk.kanzae.net/net/windows/t5591/ の記事を参考にさせて頂き、XAMPP直下のフォルダ名はPHPで維持、このフォルダ内を5.6から7.0へ一斉置き換えする対策を図りました。
（旧Verのフォルダ名は別名退避、今回取得した新たなVerのフォルダ：php-7.0.28-Win32-VC14-x86はPHPへリネーム）

この上で、Apacheを再起動したところ、コンソールへ以下が現われるようになってしまいました。
尚、旧Verのフォルダを所定のPHPという名に戻せば、通常に起動できることも確認しています。

```
13:27:14  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:27:14  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:27:14  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:27:14  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:27:14  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:27:14  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:27:14  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

この英文メッセージの中で、`Press the Logs button to view error logs`とありますが
Apacheの起動に失敗した時間帯の記載が、ApacheのErrorログ・Accessログ双方に見当たりません。
（Windowsイベントログにも記載なし）

参考にした記事に、「Apache を起動してエラーが出る場合」の対処方法も言及されていますが
現在の当方の事象と合致した対策なのかが不明で　一体何をすれば改善が見込めるのか思い悩んでいます。

#### 質問

何を試せば、Apacheを無事にできるようになりますか？
参考にさせて頂いた記事では、旧VerのPHPに関しプログラムのアンインストール操作は不要に受けてとれました。VerUpに関してフォルダ内容を挿げ替える対策は妥当なのでしょうか？
皆様のご見解をお待ちしております。

Comment: 「VerUpに関してフォルダ内容を挿げ替える対策は妥当なのでしょうか？」こちらに関してはご自分で試されてすでに結論が見えているのではないかと思うのですが? 例えばWindows版Apacheの主要なバイナリー配布には、ビルドに使っているコンパイラのバージョンによってVC11, VC14, VC15がありますが、リンク先の記事で使用しているPHPバイナリーはVC14版です。さて、あなたが先にインストールされたApacheのバージョンはVC11, VC14, VC15のどれでしょうか? VC14以外のApacheだとしたらVC14版のPHPは動くのでしょうか? このあたりは難しい問題で、やってみたら動く場合もあるでしょうし、動かない場合もあるでしょう。(ちなみにWindows版のPHP機能拡張はコンパイラーが異なると確実に動きません。)他にもhttpd.confやphp.iniなどの設定ファイルの中身が書き換わっている可能性もあり、リンク先の記事がうまく行ったのは(cubickさんの回答にあるように)本当に「たまたま」だと思った方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

参考にしたサイトではたまたま運良く差し替えが出来ただけで、XAMPPで環境を構築したのであれば
XAMPPごとアップグレードした方が余計なトラブルを避けられるのではないでしょうか。

別のサイトでは設定を事前にバックアップしたうえでXAMPPをアップグレードする手順が紹介されています。
https://gameusers.org/dev/blog/xampp-update/

---

**追記**

> PHP・Apache2.4の動作を一応確認致しましたがPHPのVerが期待外であったため

とありますが、[XAMPPのダウンロードページ](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)を見る限りは(比較的最近のリリースであれば)配布パッケージにそれぞれ何のバージョンが含まれているかが分かりますし、そもそも**XAMPPのバージョン=PHPのバージョン**が元になっているようです。
インストールするべきバージョンをよく確認してから実際の作業を行うべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: 仰られるとおり返す言葉がございません．．．今からご提示のURLを参考にXAMPPの一斉UPGRADEに挑戦してみます。

Comment: ウチの会社の都合（プロキシサーバを通している）で、ご提示のURLは開くことができませんでしたが
いづれにせよ、uninstall.exeというものを起動してアンインストールを達成するようで．．．。
それて、現在非常に困ったことが起きました。このEXEがXAMPPのフォルダに見当たらないのです。
Eclipse 4.7 oxygenのインストールで包括的にダウンロードされたXAMPPで、XAMPPを単独に入手せずこちらを
インストールしてしまったことが、PHPのVerを低くセットアップしてしまった理由です。
それはさておき、uninstall.exeがないって．．．一体私はどうしたら良いのでしょう。どこからか入手できるのでしょうか？

Comment: uninstall.exeがないことに状況は変わりないのですが、一からやり直したいです。本当に．．．．
XAMPPのアンインストールというか、Eclipse 4.7 oxygenのアンインストールなのでしょうか？
頭が痛いです。別のスレッドを立てるべきか....